# Array of dummy variables in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Say you want to integrate an expression depends on n variables and on n in n dimension in way that n can be variable as well.

Comment: Please give some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
multyIntegrate[fun_, n_Integer] :=
 With[{x = Sequence @@ Table[Unique[mi], {n}]}, Integrate[fun[x], x]]

multyIntegrate[g, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[i___] := Total[{i}.{i}]

multyIntegrate[f, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]